# How to Represent Discrete-Time Non-Linear System on MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am doing a homework, which requires me to create a tank level controller on a PLC software. In order to design an effective controller, I wanted to create the difference equation of the system first, which I have managed to.

However, the equation I achieved is non-linear. I do not know how I should create such a system with Simulink. I tried taking the Z-transform of the equation in order to find the Transfer Function, however I could not finalize that. Here is the difference equation of the system:

[image]

Here is the Z-domain Transfer function I calculated:

[image]

I do not know how to incorporate the T(z) term in the denominator of the Transfer function, in MATLAB/Simulink environment. I just want to create a system with that transfer function. Can anyone help me with that? I do not mind going with the sampled time-domain difference equation in order to have the system defined on MATLAB/Simulink.

Comment: Unless your taking a non-linear controls class, I would double check that math.

Comment: @Voltage Spike♦ So my transfer function calculation is incorrect then? Even if I correct it, can you suggest me a way to deal with that square root term? By the way, I am not taking a non-linear control class (going to take an introduction class next year), our lecturer said it is possible to create the controller by trian-and-error approach. Indeed, yes it is true, I designed a fairly successful controller by this approach. However I want to improve the transient performance more.

Comment: A few points. For non linear system, the concept of transfer function is not defined IIRC. You can either directly implement the original difference equation in simulink using `1/z` delay blocks, gain, `sqrt`, summing blocks etc. Otherwise, you can first find out the operating point and then linearise the system and find the transfer function of the linearization result. In this method, the `sqrt` will disappear during the linearisation procedure.

Comment: "*I do not know how to incorporate the T(z) term in the denominator of the Transfer function*". IMO you cannot. In the process of finding transfer function, you had to take *all* the terms with T(z) to LHS. Cant leave anything on the RHS. But the non-linearity `sqrt` prevents you from doing that. "*I do not mind going with the sampled time-domain difference equation in order to have the system defined on MATLAB/Simulink.*". If you want to simulate the system, implement this using `1/z` blocks, ..... Etc.

Comment: @AJN Thank you so much for your insights, yes I decided to use Simulink and delay blocks to simulate the system.